# Constructing a complicated rails query (or simple, i might just be dumb)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Once upon a time, my sql kung fu was strong. I have since become a client developer.

Here's the problem:
I have Feeds, Subscriptions, and Rankings
Feeds have subscriptions and rankings (one ranking for each country code)
Rankings have a feed and country code

What i need is for a given country code, get the feeds with the most subscriptions created in the last week

How on EARTH do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be exact since you didn't provide column names, etc, something like

```
select top 10 Feeds.id, Feeds.name from Feeds 
  inner join (
    select count(*) count, feedId from Subscriptions
      where date > ?
      ) as Sub on Sub.feedId=Feeds.id
  inner join Rankings on Rankings.feedId=Feeds.id
  where Rankings.countryCode=? 
  order by Sub.count desc
```

(I am less confident in this than my previous answer, but of course that was wrong...)

Comment: Almost there, i don't want to sort by rank, i want to sort by the number of subscriptions with a created_date within the last week

Comment: ah, yes, forgot that.  OK, I gave it another shot, less confident there.